# Allow PHP chown, chgrp and chmod of specific files & directories with specific user & group

Tags: php, apache, chown, chgrp

I have a directory called /folder1/folder2/folder3 where our program resides; the program houses a php gui, python CLI tools and lots of big files. The big files are uploaded via the gui and processed by the python scripts (which includes coping or moving the files around, or creating new processed versions of the files).

I am able to set the permission bits reliably for any files affected by apache by either:

```
chmod($inputs_metric_file, 0777);

//or something like
$oldmask = umask(0); 
mkdir($inputs_report_dir, 0777);
```

However this continously fails

```
chown($inputs_report_dir, "cas");
chgrp($inputs_report_dir, "casgrp");
```

With this error:

> Warning: chown(): Operation not permitted in /folder1/folder2/folder3
>   on line 45
>
> Warning: chgrp(): Operation not permitted in /folder1/folder2/folder3
>   on line 46

**Important:** apache is not a member of the casgrp; I do not want apache to be a member as it has too many permissions. I have read that apache can't change the group unless it's a member of the new group; I suspect I need to bypass that somehow and in a restricted fashion. Even if I was able to assign apache to the casgrp, I still cannot change the user.

**Why:** we really want everything in /folder1/folder2/folder3 to be assigned to cas:casgrp always.

We've added the following lines to the sudoers file:

```
apache ALL=NOPASSWD: /folder1/folder2/folder3/cli_tool1,/folder1/folder2/folder3/cli_tool2,/bin/chown 8008 /folder1/folder2/folder3/
```

I've read that in httpd you can change the following, which may provide an avenue to the goal:

> User   apache
>
> Group  apache

... but I have concerns as I really don't know what this is doing and don't want apache to have the full permissions of the cas account/group for security reasons... I only want it to be able to help keep user/group/permissions consistent in our folder hierarchy.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: This isn't programming question. Perhaps ServerFault would get you some answers.

Comment: Its both a programming question and a server admin question in my opinion; there could be a purely programming solution that I do not know about which would be prefered. I'm okay with it if someone with permissions wants to move it.

Comment: I think this is more *nix problem than PHP/Apache. [man](http://www.cfm.brown.edu/Unixhelp/Pages/tasks/change_own.html) If you have access to shell from PHP, there might be a way using sudo perhaps, but otherwise, I think this is not possible by design of *nix. Let us know of your progress.